# TabBar Project - Core Data in a tableview

Tags: ios, uitableview, core-data, uiviewcontroller

Like so many who have come before me - I'm starting this with "I'm new to iOS programming"; I've asked a few questions here and there.

I've got a project that I'm getting setup using tabbar project.

I've got 4 tabs at the bottom, one of which is "edit", when the user clicks that they're shown a view with a month picker on it.  When they select the month - the screen should load a tableview that is populated with the appropriate months entries from coredata.

I have coredata setup in my App Delegate - but I'm curious how I would then get the information into my tableview deeper in the app?

I've worked through [THIS TUTORIAL on coredata](http://www.raywenderlich.com/934/core-data-tutorial-for-ios-getting-started) and have been able to get it to work when doing master-detail project, but this is a tabbar project I'm working within.

I've been using the storyboard for most of my layout.

I keep getting errors when I try to use this line in the viewDidLoad:

```
NSManagedObjectContext *context = [self managedObjectContext];
```

The error is:

```
 No visible @interface for 'myEditPageViewController' declares the selector 'managedObjectContext'
```

My imports are:

```
#import "myEditPageViewController.h"
#import "myAppDelegate.h"
#import "CoreData/CoreData.h"
```

My current viewDidLoad looks like this (which I got from some digging online - remember, I'm pretty new to this stuff):

```
self.context = [self context];
if (self.context == nil)
{
self.context = [(myAppDelegate *)[[UIApplication sharedApplication] delegate] managedObjectContext];
}
NSFetchRequest *fetchRequest = [[NSFetchRequest alloc]init];
NSManagedObjectContext *context = [self managedObjectContext];
```

Any thoughts?  I'm trying to apply that tutorial to my app - but since it's not master-detail there are other views involved.  Just trying to get it working to display the coredata info!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Regarding the error

"No visible @interface for `myEditPageViewController` declares the selector `managedObjectContext`"

Selectors are another term for methods. The error message is saying that in the `myEditPageViewController` class, there is no method named `managedObjectContext`.

To explain the code you copied and pasted...

```
self.context = [self context];
```

//Sets the value of self.context (a `@property NSManagedObjectContext *context` to the getter of that property.

//This is redundant because `self.context` is equal to `self context]`
I suggest you look up tutorials on setters and getter, they are incredibly useful.

```
if (self.context == nil)
{
self.context = [(myAppDelegate *)[[UIApplication sharedApplication] delegate] managedObjectContext];
}
```

//This code is useful, it sets your NSManagedObjectContext to the managedObjectContext that is stored in your AppDelegate.

//Getting to the error itself, this line is redundant.
NSManagedObjectContext *context = [self managedObjectContext];
This creates a local instance variable named `context`, you really should just use your stored `@property` of `self.context`.

Comment: Thanks for the explanation - it really helped.  Clearly I have a long way to go in getting a great understanding of these things - but the getters/setters should help a bit.  My background is programming is that I generally jump into projects and fly by the seat of my pants until I get things working. :)  You've helped a lot by explaining.  Achievelimitless said the same thing essentially - but more condensed.  I wish I could mark both as acceptable answers.

Comment: You really shouldn't be calling down to the app delegate to get the managed object context; rather you should be passing it up the stack. Thankfully, Apple has finally put this recommendation into their documentation https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/DataManagement/Conceptual/CoreDataSnippets/Articles/stack.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40008283-SW1

Comment: @Abizern.. Thanx for the kind information. I was totally unaware of that. I have some doubts on that.I've posted [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21050408/how-to-get-managedobjectcontext-for-viewcontroller-other-than-getting-it-from-ap) too. Please explain if possible. Thank you

Answer (score 1):

First of all, Add following Line of code in your `myEditPageViewController.h`

```
@property(nonatomic, strong) NSManagedObjectContext *context;
```

Now replace your code in viewDidLoad with this:

```
if (self.context == nil)
{
self.context = [(myAppDelegate *)[[UIApplication sharedApplication] delegate] managedObjectContext];
}
NSFetchRequest *fetchRequest = [[NSFetchRequest alloc]init];
NSManagedObjectContext *context = [self context]; //Not necessary
```

Let me know if it does not work. As I've mentioned, you don't need to write last line, as you can directly refer to `self.context` rather than assigning it to other variable

Comment: Thanks - I wish I could mark two answers - because yours was the same as the one above.  His was a bit more extensive in explaining why certain things do what they do - so I gave him the answer.  However I gave you the upvote I could because your answer is condensed and good.

Comment: You really shouldn't be calling down to the app delegate to get the managed object context; rather you should be passing it up the stack. Thankfully, Apple has finally put this recommendation into their documentation https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/DataManagement/Conceptual/CoreDataSnippets/Articles/stack.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40008283-SW1