# Attach Managed Object Context to nested UITableViewController

Tags: ios, objective-c, core-data, uitableview

I'm trying to attach my MOC to a `UITableViewController` that has been created using Xcode 5 Storyboards.  The nesting is like this:  `UITabBarController` -> `UINavigationController` -> `UITableView`.  I'm instantiating the MOC in the `AppDelegate` and I want to pass it to the `UITableView`.  Any suggestions?

Thanks!

Thanks, the CoreDataBooks example does something like this:  But their Storyboard is directly from UINavigationController -> UITableView.

```
UINavigationController *navigationController = (UINavigationController *)self.window.rootViewController;
RootViewController *rootViewController = (RootViewController *)[[navigationController viewControllers] objectAtIndex:0];
rootViewController.managedObjectContext = self.managedObjectContext;
```

I guess I can use method #1 below but what's the proper way to identify the UITabBarController from AppDelegate?  I guess I need to instantiate that as its own class and import that into the delegate too?

Answer (score 0):

There are many ways to pass MOC from appDelegate to yourViewController. You can see a detailed discussion on this topic in [my Question here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21050408/how-to-get-managedobjectcontext-for-viewcontroller-other-than-getting-it-from-ap)

I would like to list down the possible ways:

1. Instantiate & assign MOC to your VC from appDelegate.
2. Call appDelegate from your VC by using this code:

   myAppDelegate * del= [[UIApplication sharedApplication]delegate];

& get the context like this:

```
myContext = del.context;
```

You can go through above question for a detailed argument.. :)