# Read CoreData in Today Widget in Swift or Objective-C

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, swift

I really need some **simple code** for me how to read CoreData in **TodayWidget**
This steps I made:

- Create new project with using CoreData (in AppDelegate)
- Make an Entity in CoreData model and some Attributes like a name or date
- in ViewController of App fill name and date with one record like "Martin" "10/11"

And Now I need to read this name in TodayViewController

Please really post here just some simple code from it, or how to edit AppDelegate for using appgroup ...

Thanks !

Answer (score 1):

Widgets have to be able to read the data in their code. In order to do this, you need to setup your CoreData files to be located in a 'group' folder in your project (You can set your CoreData Stack to relocate it's files in this folder). Then you'll configure a CoreData Stack in your extension that points to the same files. These group folders are folders that can be access across multiple targets/applications that have permissions for the group.

I will point out that it's far easier to use and sync NSUserDefaults across a widget and it's appropriate application than it is CoreData.

You'll want to read Apple's documentation about sharing extension data below:

[Apple docs](https://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/ios/documentation/General/Conceptual/ExtensibilityPG/ExtensionScenarios.html)

Note the following section:

> Sharing Data with Your Containing App
>
> Even though an app extension bundle is nested within its containing
>   app’s bundle, the running app extension and containing app have no
>   direct access to each other’s containers.
>
> BACKGROUND
>
> To learn about containers, read About the iOS File System in File
>   System Programming Guide.
>
> You can, however, enable data sharing. For example, you might want to
>   allow your app extension and its containing app to share a single
>   large set of data, such as prerendered assets.

Comment: but I can't manage CoreData via "SharedApplication" from AppDelegate ... Could you post some step by step solution ? I'm really confused ...

Comment: The AppDelegate has nothing to do with it, you can ignore 'managing' CoreData in the app delegate. An extension/widget is a completely different target with separate code. It is not 'part' of your application per say. Picture it as a separate application. Because of this, you must read/write data separately from your main application. Do not rely on passing data back and forth between your application and the widget/extension. Read the apple documentation about sharing data I posted above. Using what I said above, the widget and the app will share core data files, nothing more.

Comment: I'll also like to mention that there is no 'simple' code to show for this. A tutorial could be made on how to do this. It involves setting up groups and CoreData stacks in 2 separate applications.

Comment: yea but still I don't know how to access to the core data ... really I need some code sample for it ...

Comment: ... do you understand me ? I really need some code example how to read that data stored in CoreData !

Comment: I understand what you are saying, what you are asking for is beyond the scope of a simple answer in which I will not be providing you with a sample application to do what you are asking. Judging by the fact that you don't understand how to access CoreData and that you are still asking for sample code after the information I've provided. I'm fairly certain I can confirm that you don't have a good understanding of how the CoreData stack works in general. I invoke that you should read something like: http://code.tutsplus.com/tutorials/core-data-from-scratch-core-data-stack--cms-20926.

Comment: This is the important part: - (NSManagedObjectModel *)managedObjectModel
{
    if (_managedObjectModel != nil) {
        return _managedObjectModel;
    }
    NSURL *modelURL = [[NSBundle mainBundle] URLForResource:@"Core_Data" withExtension:@"momd"];
    _managedObjectModel = [[NSManagedObjectModel alloc] initWithContentsOfURL:modelURL];
    return _managedObjectModel;
}

Comment: The above points to a URL on disk and begins the process of loading those CoreData files.

Comment: Also, you may want to look into the following book: http://www.raywenderlich.com/store/core-data-by-tutorials